# Character sets offered in the Eclipse properties

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding

I've just been handed a pile of Java source that, I suspect, is in ISO-8859-8. Eclipse's menu of charsets, here on my Mac, does not include that. Or any of a wide variety of other encodings supported by the JDK.

Is there a recipe for expanding the list of encodings that show up in the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just type it in manually.  From Edit->Set Encoding..., simply type in `ISO-8859-8`.  Only a few are listed, but it will accept any that your Java runtime accepts.  After you choose it once, it should be listed in the drop-down combobox after that.

See [Supported Encodings](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) for more information on which sets are supported by Java.

If it's not the Set Encoding action you're trying to run, please give more information of what steps you're taking to get to the "menu of charsets."